# mina deploy failed from Vagrant Ubuntu/trusty32

Tags: deployment, ruby-on-rails, vagrant, daemon

I'm new to rails. Have spent this whole morning trying to debug this strange problem. I am trying to deploy my rails application using mina to a staging server. My server is Ubuntu/trusty32 14.04 running with Vagrant VM. And the server I'm trying to deploy to is CentOS release 6.6. Here is the deploy task from config/deploy.rb:

```
task :deploy => :environment do
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    to :launch do
      queue  "cd #{deploy_to}/#{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec puma -t #{puma_threads} -e #{rails_env} -d -b unix://#{deploy_to}/shared#{socket_file} --pidfile #{deploy_to}/shared#{pid_file}"
      queue "sudo echo -1000 > /proc/`cat #{deploy_to}/shared#{pid_file}`/oom_score_adj"                  
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the error I get.

> Puma starting in single mode
>
> - Version 2.11.0 (ruby 2.0.0-p598), codename: Intrepid Squirrel
> - Min threads: 0, max threads: 5
> - Environment: staging
> - Daemonizing...
>
> cat: /var/www/staging/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid: No such file or directory
>
> cat: /var/www/staging/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid: No such file or directory
>
> bash: line 176: /proc//oom_score_adj: No such file or directory
>
> ! ERROR: Deploy failed.

Strange thing is if I remove the line `` queue "sudo echo -1000 > /proc/`cat #{deploy_to}/shared#{pid_file}`/oom_score_adj" `` both pid & socket files are created. I am thinking that this line is  executing the before puma finishes daemoninizing and creating the pid file. But then again this same script works fine from another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting a random sleep between the lines seem to do the trick:

```
queue! "cd #{deploy_to}/#{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec puma -t #{puma_threads} -e #{rails_env} -d -b unix://#{deploy_to}/shared#{socket_file} --pidfile #{deploy_to}/shared#{pid_file}"
queue! "sleep 10"
queue! "sudo echo -1000 > /proc/`cat #{deploy_to}/shared#{pid_file}`/oom_score_adj"
```

But open to better solution :)